# How to update a field of a table that is inner join of another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `tablea` and `tableb`. Both of them have three columns called `columna`, `columnb` ,`columnc`.

Now I want to do this:

If `tablea.columnb` equals `tableb.columnb`,then set `tablea.columnc` = `tableb.columnc`. I have written the sql and it works well, but I think that there must be a better way to do this? Can anyone help me to optimize my sql statement, or is there any other way?

```
UPDATE tablea ta 
SET 
ta.columnc = (
              SELECT columnc FROM tableb
              WHERE ta.columnb = tableb.columnb
             )
WHERE ta.columnb IN (
                     SELECT columnb FROM tableb
                     WHERE ta.columnb = tableb.columnb
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this simple query

```
Update tablea ta,table tb set ta.columnc=tb.columnc where ta.columnb =tb.columnb;
```